# Looping trough list of lists and safe it as seperate df

Tags: python, list, dataframe, loops

I created a loop which takes the values from a df when a certain value is met in a specific column.
I safe the remaining column information in a list.
now i want to loop trough a list containing the previously created lists and transform it to a df. i want to keep the name of the list as the df name

so my second loop is not working as i wish.
it stores the last list as a df called name. but I'd like to have three df's with the names

'bereit', 'spaeter' and 'kein_int'

```js
bereit = []
spaeter = []
kein_int = []


for i in range(len(df.userid)):
    if df.iloc[i, 1] == 'okay, ich bin bereit':
        bereit.append(df.iloc[i, :])
    elif df.iloc[i, 1] == 'später starten':
        spaeter.append(df.iloc[i, :])
    elif df.iloc[i, 1] == 'kein interesse mehr':
        kein_int.append(df.iloc[i, :])

list_ans = [bereit, spaeter, kein_int]
list_ans

for name in list_ans:
    name = pd.DataFrame(name)
    name = name.reset_index(drop=True)
    print(name)


name
```